# How to compare system array and system object?

Tags: arrays, powershell, object, compare

I am trying to get Backup job information and store in $JobInfo variable.

```
$JobInfo = Invoke-Command -Session $PSSession -ScriptBlock {
            Get-VBRJob -name $Using:D_Job -PipelineVariable DJob | Get-VBRJobObject | Select-Object @{n = 'DJobName'; e = {$DJob.Name} }, @{n = 'DJobInfo'; e = { $DJob } }
        
            }

if ($JobInfo.DJobname -match $D_Job) {

"$D_Job Daily Job is present"

}
```

Script writes "Daily Job present" for both `-match` and `-notmatch` operator. I also tried with `-like`, `-notlike`, `-eq`, `-ne`. Result is same. When I display the both variables `$JobInfo.DJobname` and `$D_Job`, I see same text.

But $JobInfo.DJobname.Gettype() -> System.Array & $D_Job.Gettype() -> System-Object.

Kindly adivse.

Comment: Sounds like you want `$JobInfo.DJobname -contains $D_Job`